# Is there a way to depict verticall scroll movement of pixels using mousewheelbutton using GLSL, OpenGL in python?

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, glsl

I am developing an data viewing application in which time series data of multiple sensors is plotted. The size of data is always in Gigabytes therefore I opt to use OpenGl for this purpose.

Now I want the data to scroll vertically for better analysis of it. I am able to do this by two methods till now but none of them seems to be quite fully-complete. First method I tried was to simply change the index of sensors in an periodic manner with motion of the scroll wheel(using np.roll). Now this method completes my requirement but it looks like I am jumping data. I want an smooth transaction of scroll.

Second method was to set an position change in vertex shader. I simply passes an float value of range between -1 and 1 of Y-axis and it simply interpolates the positional data above it to the bottom. The problem with this method is whenever I reach the position when an sensor data is on the both ends (-1 and 1) it joins the lines across the whole screen.
 I am unable to understand what else can I do using shader to make this happen.
Below are the shader that I am using and [Image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4x8a.png) I am getting.
Passing data using VBO and using `gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_LINE_STRIP, i * self.count, self.count)` in a loop to make lines.

```
VS = '''uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 modelview;

layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;

uniform float level;
void main() {

    if (position.y>-level){
        gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y-(1-level), 0., 1.);
    }else
        {gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y + (1+level), 0., 1.);}'''

FS = '''#version 450
// Output variable of the fragment shader, which is a 4D vector containing the
// RGBA components of the pixel color.
uniform vec3 triangleColor;
void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(triangleColor, 1.0);}'''
```

So I was hoping to find a method in which I firstly plot data using shader and then rotate all the pixel array index

Comment: Why are you changing vertex positions explicitly if you want to move whole meshes? Just use matrix, calculate transform on the client and upload it to your vertex shader via uniform. It will make your life easier. In games there is a camera (view) matrix ,which is probably what you need to scroll your view.

Comment: I am trying to depict the full circular rotation of data lines in such a manner when I use mouse scroll, the line at the top starts to move in upward direction and when it gets out of view , it should start reappearing from bottom and same pattern for all data lines.

Comment: it doesn't matter,at the end this is purely mathematical problem which you can solve with matrix transformations.But if you add some images of the concept it might help.

Comment: If I translate the data using matrix translations, then yes, It gives me the desired scroll functionality but whenever a line is intersected at the top or bottom(means some of the line is at the top while rest at bottom) it joins them. I have added an image in original question which depicts this behaviour. I guess I have to render lines it in an Texture and then use translation matrix.